# Impossible to retrieve nested association from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm a bit new to rails and I'm having a problem I try to retrieve a "proposition" object in a controller.

my datamodel is :
user -> ad -> proposition

So I created the below "proposition" model :

```
class Proposition < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :ad
attr_accessible :email, :name
end
```

Therefore, we have an association between an "ad" and "proposition" (many propositions can be associated to an ad).

In the same way, the "ads" belongs to a user :

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
...
```

No problem when I try to retrieve the ads from a given user :

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
def edit
@ads = current_user.ads
```

But when I try to retrieve the associated proposition :

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
def edit
@ads = current_user.ads
@propositions = current_user.ads.propositions
```

I get the following error message :

```
undefined method `propositions' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fee649009c0>
```

Any guess what's going on ?

Thanks

Comment: Is that your `full code` of your `Ad` model that you posted?

Comment: is your database model like this: A user has many ads and an ad has many prepositions?

Answer (score 6):

The error you have is caused by the fact you have relation, and the `propositions` (if you have the `has_many :propositions` in your `Ad` class) is defined on an instance of `Ad`.

So this means that

```
ad = Ad.first
ad.propositions
```

will work, but `current_user.ads.propositions` will not.

I am assuming you want to find all proposition linked to a user, through the ads. In that case it is pretty simple to fix.

In your user model write

```
class User
  has_many :ads
  has_many :propositions, through: :ads
end
```

make sure `Ad` has the needed relations:

```
class Ad
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :propositions
end
```

and then in your controller, you can just write

```
@propositions = current_user.propositions
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank tou so much for your quick answer nathanvda. That works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the other side of the relation for this to work:

```
class Ad
  has_many :propositions
end
```

Now, your `current_user.ads.propositions` will not work anyway, as the 'propositions' are for a single ad. If you want to be able to collect all propositions for all ads for a single users, you could create a method such as:

```
class User
  has_many :ads

  all_props = []
  def propositions
    ads.each {|ad| all_props += ad.propositions}
  end
end
```

Comment: He definitely needs it, but this will not work :) Adding the  `propositions` relation, defines it only on a single instance of an `Ad`.

Comment: You may well be right - 'current_user.ads.propositions' will not work anyway. I'll update accordingly

Comment: OMG! Check my answer, there is a really simple solution.

Comment: You are against right. I should think before typing. You'll get my +1

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong but from the look of your code i think you have a database model with a user having many ads and an ad having many propositions. You need to define your database models like this:

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ads
end
```

Ad model:

```
class Ad < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :propositions
  belongs_to :user #if you want to extract user with a specific ad
end
```

and in your registerations controller you need to do something like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def edit
    @ads = current_user.ads  #returns a collection of ads for current user
    @ad = current_user.ads.find(params[:id]) #find and returns your specific ad
    @propositions = @ad.propositions #returns a collection of propositions related to your ad
  end
end
```

Comment: This will only give the propositions of a single ad, not all propositions linked to a user.

Comment: @nathanvda I know!! He is finding propositions by calling "current_user.ads.propositions" (notice ads and propositions which suggest a user has many ads and ad has many propositions) and havent mentioned if he wants all the propositions related to a user or related to a particular ad